# Byte[] to String java 1.5

Tags: java

I am trying the below code :-

```
private Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
String decryptedtext = new String(decryptedValue, charset);
```

where `decryptedValue` is of type `byte[]` but the above code is not working for java 1.5 version. I am getting the error as below :-

```
> ERROR: symbol : constructor String(byte[],java.nio.charset.Charset)
> ERROR: location: class java.lang.String
> ERROR: String decryptedtext = new String(decryptedValue, charset); 
> ERROR: ^
```

Can anyone help me on this ?

Apologies in advance if this is a repetitive or duplicate question.

Comment: That constructor was added in Java 1.6

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-byte:A-java.nio.charset.Charset-

Comment: You should not use such an old java version. It is outdated since many years

Comment: Here is the Java 5 docs for `String`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: @Jens The application is based on Java 1.5 and have not migrated to the latest java release

Comment: @dimo414 Thank you for the documentation :)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thank you for the documentation :)

Comment: @Eran yes the constructor was added in Java 1.6, but the application which i am working is still on java 1.5 :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `String(byte[], Charset)` constructor in Java 5. You can only use [`String(byte[], String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[],%20java.lang.String)). Then your code should look like:

```
String s = new String(decryptedValue, "UTF-8");
```